# Perl shell one-liner: picking last field of the last line of stdin

Tags: perl

Given an output like this:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 tinosino  staff   4.0K 21 Mar  2012 EtcHosts_Backup_2012-03-21_21-19-10.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 tinosino  staff   3.8K  1 Apr  2012 EtcHosts_Backup_2012-04-01_01-06-12.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 tinosino  staff   3.9K 18 Jun  2012 EtcHosts_Backup_2012-06-18_18-33-40.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 tinosino  staff   3.9K 27 Aug  2012 EtcHosts_Backup_2012-08-27_09-37-44.txt
```

I'd like to get the last field (the filename) of the last line (27 Aug), basically:

```
EtcHosts_Backup_2012-08-27_09-37-44.txt
```

I am interested in how to best do this in `perl`.

If there is a better way to do this with just `ls`, it is not what I am looking for (I know I can sort by date, creation, modification, etc. and I can `-1t` to just show the filename)

This is essentially about learning how to do in `perl` what I generally do in `awk`:

```
ll | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $NF}'
```

giving:

```
EtcHosts_Backup_2012-08-27_09-37-44.txt
```

Which is "the desired answer".

Here my attempt:

```
ll | perl -lane 'eof() && print $F[$#F]'
```

Could I improve on this ugly-looking piece of.. F? `$F[$#F]`

The answer "seems right", yet the way to get $NF seems primordial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improvement:

```
perl -lane 'eof() && print $F[-1]'  # or ...
perl -lane 'eof() && print pop @F'
```

Further:

```
perl -lane 'END { print $F[-1] }'   # or...
perl -lane 'END { print pop @F }'
```

and of course, why not just:

```
ls | tail -1
```

Comment: Thanks! I **love** the `print pop @F`! Of course not `ls | tail -1` because I _did_ say it was just an example to learn `perl` way of `$NF`. Nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question about improving on `$F[$#F]`, Perl supports using negative numbers as array indices.  For example, -1 refers to the last element of the list, so you could write your one-liner as:

```
ll | perl -lane 'eof() && print $F[-1]'
```